# DataGridView RowFilter By Date

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, datatable, rowfilter

My `dataGridView_flaggedComments` has, let say, 10 rows. Value in the `Comments_Date` column's cell shows dates in the format of `31/12/2014 12:01 PM`, if I choose a date (which is without time portion) from `comboBox_stockDates` (e.g. 31/12/2014), I want it to filter (and display) all the rows that have `31/12/2014 xx:xx xx`.

The below code would yield zero result even when the selected date (e.g. 31/12/2014) matches the rows which contain `31/12/2014 xx:xx xx`. Any idea what has gone wrong here?

```
string dtFilter = string.Format("Comments_Date = #{0}#", comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString());
(dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = dtFilter;
```

Alternatively, is there a way to convert both dates to string then compare? I tried to use LIKE operator but error says cannot be used to compare between DateTime and String.

Any help and guidance would be much appreciated! Thank you. :)

Comment: for example you could do something like this 
`string dtFilter = string.Format("Comments_Date ={0} ", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));` also you do not need to `#` signs at all you need to convert the DateTime value to a string then do the comparison if I understand you correctly

Comment: Hi DJ KRAZE, thanks for trying, but this `string dtFilter = string.Format("Comments_Date = {0}", comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString());` won't work. Error: `Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.Double.`

Comment: can you show the exact text that you are getting from the dropdown what I have shown is something that you can use as a testing purpose.. and where are you getting system.double..?

Comment: I'm getting system.double error when there's no single quote around `{0}`. The exact text from the dropdown would be in this format `31/12/2014`.

Comment: You need Double Quotes around your Parameter `"{0}"` not `'{0}'` MSDN Reference [string.Format "{0}"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi, it's not possible to do double quote because it's being used to quote the string like `string dtFilter = string.Format("Comments_Date >= "{0}"", comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Comment: With my code, I think I know why there's zero result. Because if I choose "05/09/2014" (dd/MM/yyyy) from the combobox, it's trying to filter "05/09/2014" (MM/dd/yyyy), hence no result. But I don't know how to make the datagridview `Comments_Date` column's dates to follow `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")` so that it reads the date correctly as dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Thanks for the link! But I'm just lost on how to code that into my code.

Comment: I am confused.. it shows you an example doesn't it..? do a google search on `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")`

Comment: Don't confuse. I am not a programmer, I do this part of my research. So that's why.. `string dtFilter = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), "Comments_Date = #{0}#", comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString());` still showing zero result. I will deal with it, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this fixed, so I propose my own answer. It might be of helpful in the future for someone who's looking for similar question.

```
string str = comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString();
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
string dtFilter = string.Format(
    "[Comments_Date] >= '{0} 12:00:00 AM' AND [Comments_Date] <= '{0} 11:59:59 PM'", date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
(dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = dtFilter;
```