# C# compare time string in datagrid to current time

Tags: c#

I am looking for some assistance to an issue I'm having. I am trying to create a datagrid filter with one of the columns being 'Time' with the data being read in from a text file in a string format as 16:23 etc., I need to compare it with the current time and if greater to output to the datagrid.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Operator", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Bus Stop", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Destination", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));

// ...

string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Time = #" + >= currentTime  + "#", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Ariel", 9);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: So what is your question? What is your problem here?

Comment: Sorry, I need to compare the time being read in to the current time and if the time being read in is greater than the current time to output it into a datagrid. I am reading the data in as:

    X34;Stagecoach;ASDA;Newcastle;Saturday;16:48
    X34;Stagecoach;ASDA;Newcastle;Saturday;18:03
    X34;Stagecoach;ASDA;Newcastle;Saturday;18:47

Comment: this is not a difficult task there are actually tons of examples on how to compare the datetime of one value if it's >= to another. have you even tried to use `Google`

Comment: Why you don't filter values before to add to DataTable `table`?

Comment: The data I am reading in is in a string format and the datafilter is also in the same format, it's trying to compare the string to a datetime that is the problem and I know you can't compare a string to a string if I convert the datetime.now.tostring.

Comment: I am reading in the data from a text file, then filtering on it then outputting to a datagrid.

Comment: here is one example you can try hope it's not too confusing for you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855493/datagridview-rowfilter-by-

Comment: Thanks Methodman, I'll have a gander at it now.. :)